# How to use Rest Template to step into a JSON object?

Tags: json, spring, resttemplate

I have learned how to use a rest template to access a JSON array like this:

```
[
    {
        "ID": "0ae6496f-bb0b-4ebd-a094-ca766e82f3e7",
        "Confirmed": 0,
    }
    {
        "ID": "e010ced5-c7cb-4090-a7ed-206f4c482a5b",
        "Confirmed": 0,
    }
]
```

I accessed the `Confirmed` for example with

```
public Model[] getModel() {
    ResponseEntity<Model[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(apiUrl, Model[].class);
    return response.getBody();
}
```

but now I have to access data in another Json from another API. The data looks like this

```
{
    "prefixes": [
        {
            "region": "ap-northeast-2",
            "service": "AMAZON",
        },
        {
            "region": "eu-west-3",
            "service": "AMAZON",
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I access `region` or `service` inside, and what would be the proper name for this?

The first is a JSON array, the second a JSON object?

The first API is simply

> https://example.com

Whereas the second is

> https://example.com/data.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the POJO for return type:

```
List<RegionServiceObject> items;
```

Where `RegionServiceObject` looks:

```
public class RegionServiceObject {
    private String region;
    private String service;
    // constructors, getters/setters, toString()....
}
```

The way of deseariliseing to object is similar to which you already wrote:

```
RegionServiceObject[] items = restTemplate.getForObject(url, RegionServiceObject[].class);
```

and access for specific item will be as usual for specific `item`:

```
for (RegionServiceObject item : items) {
    item.getRegion();
    item.getService();
    // use them here
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this with more details? I am really new to java.

Comment: thanks, will try tomorrow morning, it´s after midnight for me. i think in combination with a tutorial i just found (https://dzone.com/articles/deserializing-json-java-object) i can make it work.

Comment: Hey, thanks again for your answer. I still don´t really understand this, so I went ahead and just played around with it for a while. I ended up using a different approach and instead of RestTemplate used Unirest.get(url).asString.getBody() and now i think i can filter the data somehow.